# How to jump on haystack on Inferno?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

In CS:GO Inferno map, there is a haystack which I have seen people jump up onto (which then allows them to jump across to the balcony). However no matter how much I try I can't seem to do it myself. Is there some trick to it?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go stand on the metal piece (X on the image) and then jump slightly towards the center of the alley (arrow on the image indicates direction), crouch and strafe towards the cart.

[image: Cart\<- X]

Video demonstration:

Comment: Crouching after jumping is what I wasn't doing. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Only trick is that it's slanted downward to the left. So you can't jump straight forward, you have to angle your jump to the left (away from the building).

That's all, pretty easy once you understand.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong about this, but my impression is that jumping and then crouching at the peak of your jump allows you to climb onto more things than just a simple crouch-jump. That's what I do whenever I try to get on the haystack, though you might have to do what 3ventic says too.